# How to sleep a certain amount of seconds in the Phaser-Framework

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

In my game i'm trying to make a variable go up gradually, so i need to be able to sleep a certain amount of time before I increment the variable again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use a timer. This will allow you to execute one off delayed events, or execute that function call repeatedly.

An example, as the phaser website basically gives you examples of *everything* if you search for it,
http://phaser.io/examples/v2/time/basic-timed-event

Also, from the docs
http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.8/Phaser.Timer.html

Should you need to repeat, note the function "loop" (I would post the link, but i don't have enough reputation yet).

2) The alternative is simply to tie in to Phaser's game tick. Within your state (if this is where you are executing you variable incrementation), create an update function (this will be called every game update). You can access time since last update.

Look up the class Phaser.Timer (again, i cannot post the link).
See the properties elapsed and elapsedMS. You could use this to manually track time elapsed since your last incremental event (behind the scenes, this is basically what phaser tweens or timed events are doing).

eg:

```js
var timeSinceLastIncrement = 0;

function update()
{
  // Update the variable that tracks total time elapsed
  timeSinceLastIncrement += game.time.elapsed;
  
  if (timeSinceLastIncrement >= 10)  // eg, update every 10 seconds
  {
    timeSinceLastIncreemnt = 0;
    
    // Do your timed code here.
  }
}
```

Note, that option 1 is cleaner, and likely to be the preferred solution. I present option 2 simply to suggest how this can be done manually (and in fact, how it is generally done in frameworks like phaser behind the scenes).